# How to find directory structure in Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, find

I am looking for a Linux command in `RHEL v6.x` to search a particular directory structure in the current directory.

Though I know the below command which will search a particular single directory in the current directory which is working for a single directory but not for the directory structure.

Working:

```
find /home/dir1/* -name "def"
```

Not Working:

```
find /home/dir1/* -name "abc/def"
```

I also tried below command but it is also listing the files inside this directory But I don't want to list the file inside this directory. I only want to list the full path of all the directory which has got this `abc/def` directory structure.

```
locate abc/def/
```

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: How the manual describes `-name`: "Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches shell pattern pattern."

Comment: Under man find for -name, it **explicitly states**: Because the  leading  directories  are removed,  the  file names considered for a match with -name will never include a slash, so `-name a/b' will never match anything (you  probably  need to use -path instead).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-name` test only matches the last path component. To match something like `abc/def` you will need `-path`:

```
$ mkdir -p somedir/otherdir/abc/def/ghi
$ find somedir -path '*/abc/def'
somedir/otherdir/abc/def
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
find /home/dir1/ -type d | grep 'abc/def'
```

or ff you only want to list directories up to a certain depth.

```
find /home/dir1/ -maxdepth 2 -type d | grep 'abc/def'
```

`-d - directory`

`-maxdepth levels of directories below the starting-points.`

Comment: If POSIX find provides `-path`, there is no advantage in piping find's output to a separate process.

Comment: Maybe so, but it works and should not be discounted as an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
tree <base dir>
       -L level
             Max display depth of the directory tree.
       -P pattern
              List  only those files that match the wild-card pattern.
```

Comment: Perhaps your answer could be enhanced to address "I only want to list the full patch of all the directory which has got this abc/def directory structure" instead of just being a copy of the man-page?